# Memory usage for a SceneKit based app is significantly higher in iOS 12

Tags: ios, scenekit

For a SceneKit based app running in **iOS 12**, we are seeing significantly higher memory usage.

To duplicate, make a new project with the iOS Game Template in **Xcode 10**. Don't make any changes. Just compile and run it on different iOS devices.

Here is what we found:

```
iPhone 6 Plus    (iOS 12):      44 MB
iPhone 6S Plus   (iOS 11.4):    21 MB
iPad Air 2:      (iOS 11.4):    18 MB
iPadPro (12.9):  (iOS 12.1):   104 MB

Note: Memory values from Xcode Debug Navigator
```

Some variance was expected not 2X for the iOS 12 based device. Selected rendering API: Default.

Is there a default setting that we can tweak to get lower/normal memory usage behavior?

Updated with iPadPro numbers.

Bug report filed: #**46170101**

```
vmmap -summary  example1.memgraph  

// snippets from the 2 memorygraphs

iPadPro 12.9
---------------
Physical footprint:         100.6M
Physical footprint (peak):  168.5M

iPad Air 2
---------------
Physical footprint:         22.1M
Physical footprint (peak):  22.3M
```

Slight variation in footprint but in the same ballpark (18 vs 22.1  & 100 vs 104).

Comment: Could be a bug—would you mind [filing a report](https://bugreport.apple.com) with a sample project?

Comment: I always had doubts about the debug stats reported memory usage of SceneKit/Metal apps. A few years back I released a SceneKit based app that was quite memory intensive. What I noted was that the amount of memory I expected to be consumed was less than reported. Say it loaded 40 2000x2000 Int16 textures, you'd expect to see an absolute minimum of 320mb in the debug stats; quite often I'd see less. *It may be that we are now getting the correct memory usage in iOS 12.*